# Grails Spring Security url intercept exclude one url from pattern restriction

Tags: grails, spring-security

Using grails spring security plugin, how do I make an exception to an intercept rule.
I want to lock down most urls in a directory with a couple of exceptions.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [

//allow low level users to view
"/projects/list":["IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY","ROLE_CASUAL"],
//lock down all others
"/projects/**":["IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY","ROLE_MANAGER"]
]
```

The wild card overrides the exception to the rule. 
Reversing the order doesn't work either.

Comment: The order looks fine. Do you by any chance have a rule before the ones you show here that might intercept the ones you show before it reaches them?

Comment: I'll double check, but I don't think so.